# LWC - Extracting data from a JSON Object

Tags: lightning-web-components, json

I trying to extract the values from a JSON object.
This is the code to console log the retrieved record data -

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

And here is the output in the JSON viewer

[image]

And this is the code I wrote to extract just the value of the Segment_ID__c field

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.fields.Segment_ID__c.value));
```

Below is the snip of the error I get when I load the record page

[image]

Reference for **Matthew Souther**

Matthew here is full code -

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import loadPersonalizedOffers from "@salesforce/apex/PersonalizedOffersController.loadPersonalizedOffers";

let FIELDS = ['Account.Segment_ID__c'];

export default class Personalized_offers extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @track segment;
    
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$recordId',
        fields: FIELDS
      }) segmentId( data, error ) {
          if(data) {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.fields.Segment_ID__c.value));
          }
          else if(error) {
           
          }
      };
}
```

EDIT - Raw Output

1. **console.log(JSON.stringify(data));**
   {"data":{"apiName":"Account","childRelationships":{},"id":"0011700001IAt7EAAT","lastModifiedById":"00517000007IbsaAAC","lastModifiedDate":"2021-02-06T18:26:54.000Z","recordTypeId":"01241000001AMf6AAG","recordTypeInfo":{"available":true,"defaultRecordTypeMapping":false,"master":false,"name":"Customer","recordTypeId":"01241000001AMf6AAG"},"systemModstamp":"2021-02-06T18:26:54.000Z","fields":{"Segment_ID__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a2n17000000EhO7AAK"}}}}
2. console.log(JSON.Stringify(data.fields));
   [image]

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you're getting this error on the console log line you shared, or if there are other references to `Segment_ID__c` in your JavaScript code that might have an issue.  Can you share the full contents of the .js file?

Comment: Matthew Souther, I have added the full js code to the post. The first console.log I am getting the data on the console log without any errors, the second one I don't see anything on console.log, but I get that error snip when I load a record.

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging your JS?  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.debug_dev_tools

Comment: That code should work, based on what I'm able to see.  Something isn't adding up.  Can you provide the raw JSON output for `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.fields))`?

Comment: @MatthewSouther I have added the raw output to the original post. I thought this would be something quite easy as I have seen everywhere on the internet, but for some reason I am stuck on this for a day now.

Comment: Any idea why it is firing twice when I have it inside if(data)

Comment: Not sure what's going on.  Not being able to get my hands on it directly, I think @NickCook's suggestion makes sense -- see what you can get out of debugging.

Comment: Okay, I am going to have a hard time with this I guess

Comment: if JSON.stringify(data) is returning `{"data":{"apiName":"Account","childRelationships":{},"id":"0011700001IAt7EAAT","lastModifiedById":"00517000007IbsaAAC","lastModifiedDate":"2021-02-06T18:26:54.000Z","recordTypeId":"01241000001AMf6AAG","recordTypeInfo":{"available":true,"defaultRecordTypeMapping":false,"master":false,"name":"Customer","recordTypeId":"01241000001AMf6AAG"},"systemModstamp":"2021-02-06T18:26:54.000Z","fields":{"Segment_ID__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a2n17000000EhO7AAK"}}}}` then shouldn't you be trying to access your data using data.data.fields ?

Comment: @glls just tried that, still not working - here is the error I get when I load the record page [Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined]

Comment: Does this mean it is an issue with getRecord method?

Comment: instead of `segmentId( data, error ) {` can you try `segmentId( {data, error} ) {`

Comment: Thanks @NickCook, that was awesome, it worked, I am so happy. Can you put it as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is telling you that `data.fields` is undefined.

Looking at your code, you have `segmentId( data, error ) {` which is essentially declaring two objects to be passed into your function.

As per the docs (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about), you need a single object with a `data` and `error` property.

Therefore you need to replace `segmentId( data, error ) {` with `segmentId( { data, error } ) {`

Comment: Thanks Nick. Appreciate it.